# I am getting the following error message - Error: Unknown property 'OpportunityStandardController.line2

Tags: visualforce, date, time

> Error: Unknown property 'OpportunityStandardController.line2

here is my code up to where I get stuck:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" showHeader="false" renderas="pdf">

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table1">
    <p align="right">
        <img src='{!URLFOR($Resource.SF_Logo_TI)}' title="logo" /></p>
        <tr align="right">    <td><font face="Arial"></font>        
</td></tr>
<hr/>
</table>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table1">

        <td width="0%"></td>
   <td align="left"><font face="Arial">Invoice number: <apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.Invoices__r}" var="line2">
   {!line2.name}</apex:repeat></font><br/>

   <font face="Arial">Invoice Date: <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}">
        <apex:param value="{!line2.Invoice_Date__c}"/>
        </apex:outputText></font></td>
```

I am trying to show the standard date format, I was using apex:repeat which was giving me the dd.mm.dd 00:00:00 yyyy

Comment: can you put a bit more code ? where line2 is coming from ?

Answer (score 1):

You've closed your `<apex:repeat>` tag early. The only reason `line2` is defined when you output its name is because you have defined it by your `var` attribute on that `<apex:repeat>`.

**Works**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.Invoices__r}" var="line2">
    <!-- inside this repeat tag, line2 is defined -->

    {!line2.Name}
    <apex:outputText value="{!0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}">
        <apex:param value="{!line2.Invoice_Date__c}" />
    </apex:outputText>

</apex:repeat>
```

**Fails**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.Invoices__r}" var="line2">
    <!-- inside this repeat tag, line2 is defined -->

    {!line2.Name}

</apex:repeat>

<!-- outside the repeat tag, line2 is not defined -->
<apex:outputText value="{!0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!line2.Invoice_Date__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

As a side note, you may find that consistent indentation and spacing will make it easier to tell how your components are nested.